# using Google Chrome Live Captioning with microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microphone, caption

I've used the following code to capture the microphone input and play it in a browser page (Google Chrome Windows10) using an audio player. That works fine, but the 'automatic' Live Captioning does not. If I drag a pre-recorded mp3 file onto a browser page and play it, the Live Captioning works fine. Where am I going wrong?

```
<body>
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
<script>
  const player = document.getElementById('player');
  const handleSuccess = function (stream) {
    if (window.URL) {
      player.srcObject = stream;
    } else {
      player.src = stream;
    }
  };
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
    .then(handleSuccess);
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks - webcaptioner only works with an internet connection, whereas Chrome captioning works offline with an mp3 file as input

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  Why not try VLC :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/44655/how-do-i-stream-my-microphone-via-vlc  on a Windows 10 PC (as VLC is cross-platform this functionality is likely available on PC as well) with a USB headset/microphone, to see if the Chrome built-in captioner can caption my voice.

You could also try https://webcaptioner.com